# PHP namespace with Dynamic class name

Tags: php, namespaces

Wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem when utilizing the new ability to namespace classes using PHP 5.3.

I am generating a dynamic class call utilizing a separate class for defining user types in my application.  Basically the class definer takes an integer representation of types and interprets them, returning a string containing the classname to be called as the model for that user.

I have an object model for the user's type with that name defined in the global scope, but I have another object with the same name for the user's editor in the Editor namespace.  For some reason, PHP won't allow me to make a namespaced dynamic call as follows.

```
$definition = Definer::defineProfile($_SESSION['user']->UserType);
new \Editor\$definition();
```

The identical syntax works for calling the global basic object model in the global namespace and I use it this way reliably throughout the application.

```
$definition = Definer::defineProfile($_SESSION['user']->UserType);
new $definition();
```

This will correctly call the dynamically desired class.

Is there a reason the two would behave differently, or has dynamic calling for namespaces not been implemented in this manor yet as this is a new feature?  Is there another way to dynamically call a class from another namespace without explicitly placing its name in the code, but from within a variable?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Well, just spell out the namespace in the string:

```
$definition = Definer::defineProfile($_SESSION['user']->UserType);
$class = '\\Editor\\' . $definition;
$foo = new $class();
```

And if it's a child namespace (as indicated in the comments), simply prepend the namespace with `__NAMESPACE__`:

```
$class = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Editor\\' . $definition;
```

So if the current namespace is `\Foo\Bar`, and `$definition` is "Baz", the resulting class would be `\Foo\Bar\Editor\Baz`

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I get an epic fail for not thinking of just appending this to the string.  Thanks!

Comment: Or don't escape the `\\` for better readability. IMHO. LOL Markdown doesn't work for just a backslash: `\` or an escaped backslash: `\\` (wow now it's very wrong!)

Comment: @Ruddie: I much prefer always escaping the backslash.  That way, any time you see a double backslash you know it's a literal backslash, and any time you see a single one you know it's escaping something else after it...  Just my experience and preference...

Comment: This answer is good, but doesn't work for namespaces that are not fully qualified -- ie if the original question had not wanted the leading backslash before `Editor` (eg if he wanted to reference a child namespace within the current namespace), then applying this answer but without the leading backslash would not have resolved the namespace correctly. Still trying to find a solution to this that doesn't involve me building up the entire fully-qualified-namespace-plus-classname as a string.

Comment: @SDC Have encountered the same problem. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Thanks Man! It save me a lot of time :)
I knew it must be possible, but couldn't find that it is such easy :)

Comment: @SDC, better late than never. You can always turn a non-fully-qualified namespace into a fully-qualified one. The point being that when you reference a classname by a string, you *must* **always** use a fully-qualified namespace.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado - You get an epic win for asking such a helpful question. Thanks!