# Lead backslash at the beginning of dynamic class name

Tags: php, apache, namespaces, php-5.3

The code:

```
$className = '\MyNamespace\MyClass';
$object = new $className();
```

throws error 'Class not found'

But this code:

```
$object = new \MyNamespace\MyClass();
```

is not.

First code fragment works at staging but not at my local. Do I need to enable something at my local server?

Many thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace with Dynamic class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513366/php-namespace-with-dynamic-class-name)

Comment: At your local, are you sure to have a PHP version > 5.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic functions *always* require a fully-qualified namespace name and as such a leading `\` would be redundant. That's why you shouldn't specify it:

```
$className = 'MyNamespace\MyClass';
$object = new $className();
```

But still, it shouldn't throw an error. Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/D8H19r

Comment: If it were only redundant, that wouldn't be a problem. Apparantly it's more. Sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just see what the string `$className` contains. You'll notice, that you should always skip the first slash.

You may create some helper to create the object for you, and strip the trailing slash if any.
`new` is evil anyway ;)