# How to declare class in namespace from string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP namespace with Dynamic class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513366/php-namespace-with-dynamic-class-name)

How to declare class from string?

## code

```
$name = 'the_class';
require_once $name.'.php';
$class = new \resource\$name();
```

## error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That's incorrect.  See some of the answers below for how to do this properly.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: That's fantastic, although very ugly. I'm still amazed that chosen syntax for namespaces was backslash, which is pretty much universally an escape character.

Comment: @Wesley Murch, it was one of the only unused characters available for syntax.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: `★resource★classname()` would be much cooler.

Comment: It's too bad that other characters couldn't be used, and have the interpreter simply recognize the context in which it was used. For example why would `$class = new Resource.Classname();` be an issue unless it was a shortcoming of the compiler? There's no ambiguity because the `.` could never work for concatenation in that context (right?). Just some thoughts - I'm sure there's a reason, it's really over my head, and I've gotten used to the backslash and almost like it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to [dynamically construct the namespace path](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php):

```
$classPath = '\\resource\\' . $name;
$class = new $classPath;
```

**Note:** I like to be explicit with [literal backslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Answer (score 4):

The namespace needs to be part of the string:

```
$name = 'the_class';
require_once $name . '.php';
$className = '\resource\\' . $name;
$class = new $className();
```