# Namespaced class not found

Tags: php, class, yii, autoload

I have the following which works just fine:

```
use frontend\models\modules\shipping\Usps;

$shipping = new Usps;
```

If however I use the following it throws the error:  Class 'Usps' not found

```
use frontend\models\modules\shippingl\Usps;
```

I am loading classes dynamically, thus I cannot use the namespace when calling new $class, eg. I might also have:

```
use frontend\models\modules\payment\Usps;

$class = 'Usps';    
$shipping = new $class;
```

How can I make this work using a variable?  If I don't use namespaces/autoload and just include the class file it works just fine.

This question is not a duplicate, the referenced question/answers do not declare a 'use'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace with Dynamic class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513366/php-namespace-with-dynamic-class-name)  In short, try this: `$class = 'frontend\\models\\modules\\shippingl\\Usps'`;

Comment: No, that will not work at all.  I am loading the classes dynamically, thus I might also have use frontend\models\modules\payment\Authorizenet;  That's a different namespace.

Comment: I guess you are autoloading with composer? Can you check the vendor/composer folder and verify that the classmaps / namespaces / psr4 (whatever you are using) is being generated?

Comment: Yes, everything is autoloaded. The namespaces are all correct.  The class will initialize if I use as suggested by watcher. The classes load just fine if I use as I showed in my first example.  They just won't load if I use a variable. Why?

Comment: I would still like an answer to this question, however I have found a way around it.  The last part of my namespaces are actually carried in the URL, so I am able to construct the namespaces using that, eg. $namespace =  '\\frontend\\models\\modules\\' . $set . '\\';  $class = $namespace . $class;

Comment: @Backslider to quote [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) on this language feature: "One must use the fully qualified name".  There's no way around it.  You must build your variable class name up _with the namespace_

Comment: I know this a little bit stupid. Is that `shippingl` not a typo? If not, did you change your `Usps` namespace to `namespace frontend\models\modules\shippingl;`

Comment: Raynal, that is just a typo with what I added here, it doesn't exist in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I see this working without security issues and tons of errors, especially if `$class` coming from user input.

I added a "Ups" class so it makes a little more sense.

```
 use frontend\models\modules\payment\Usps;
 use frontend\models\modules\payment\Ups;

 if($class == 'Usps') {    
      $shipping = new Usps;
 } else if($class == 'Ups') {
      $shipping = new Ups;
 } else {
      // No valid class found - handle accordingly
 }
```