# What is right way to create new class dynamically?

Tags: php

I have next directories tree:

> Transport
> --Transport.php
> --Curl.php
>
> SDK.php

SDK.php is namespace MySDK and class SDK, in that class I have method:

```
protected function _getTransport()
{
    if (!($this->_transport instanceof Transport\Transport)) {
        $className = 'Transport\\' . ucfirst($this->getOption('transport'));
        $this->_transport = new $className();
    }
    return $this->_transport;
}
```

But I get error message: Fatal error: Class 'Transport\Curl' not found in /path/to/repo/lib/SDK.php
And when I change `$this->_transport = new $className();` to `$this->_transport = new Transport\Curl();` I will get instance of `Transport\Curl` well.

Please help me, where did I make mistake?

Comment: Where is your class autoloader?

Comment: Sounds like a namespace issue. Are you using composer and PSR-0 or PSR-4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with a `\` or prefixed namespace as per [PHP namespace with Dynamic class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513366/php-namespace-with-dynamic-class-name)

```
$className = '\\Transport\\' . ucfirst($this->getOption('transport'));
```

Comment: Correct. But it is not clear if the OP uses `\\MySDK'\\Transport\\' . ucfirst($this->getOption('transport'));` or
`'\\Transport\\' . ucfirst($this->getOption('transport'));`

Comment: When I wrote `__NAMESPACE__ . '\\Transport\\' . ucfirst($this->getOption('transport'))` it becomes work.