# Can I use a variable as the name of a class?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

This works as well:

```
$news_single = news::whereid($post_id)->first();
```

But this throws an error:

```
$class_name  = 'news';
$news_single = $class_name::whereid($post_id)->first();
```

**Error:**

> FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 20:
>   Class 'news' not found

How can I fix it?

---

My intent of using a variable as the name of class is making a dynamic query *(kinda)*. I mean I get the class name of the URL and specify proper *Model* by it. Something like this:

```
public function ShowPost(Request $request){
    $post_id    = $request->segment(2);
    $class_name = $request->segment(1);
    $post       = $class_name::whereid($post_id)->first();
    return view('ShowPost',compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: {yes} but i would consider it a bad idea

Comment: @nogad Why a bad idea?

Comment: @stack any namespace to class??

Comment: @ThunderBird Yes I have attached that class like this `use App\news;`.. As I've mentioned in the question, this works `news::whereid($post_id)->first();`. But this doesn't work: `$class_name::whereid($post_id)->first();`

Comment: I am not sure too it will work

Comment: [Helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513366/php-namespace-with-dynamic-class-name)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `news` class in some namespace.

You have to prepend the namespace to the string.

```
$class_name  =  'App\\' .'news';
$news_single = $class_name::whereid($post_id)->first();
```